# Binding of Custom Formatted TimeSpan Using DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I'm building an ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC web app using EF Core. I have a model which has a `TimeSpan` property. I want the entered time (mm:ss) to be between `01:00` and `59:59`, so I do not want to show the hours part of the TimeSpan, as it is zero in any case. To achieve this, I added `DisplayFormat` attribute to my property. Because I want working client-side validation, I added a `RegularExpression` attribute too:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:mm\:ss}")]
[RegularExpression(@"((0?0:)?([0-3]?[0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?)", ErrorMessage = "Die Dauer muss zwischen 01:00 und 30:00 liegen")]
public TimeSpan SlotDuration { get; set; }
```

(I do know that my regex does not validate the *at least one minute thing*, but thats not my point.)

Now I do observe the following:

1. When loading my *Edit* page for an entity with 20 minutes slot duration, `20:00` is shown as expected. If I submit the request, model validation fails with my regex attribute's ErrorMessage.
2. Doing the same thing as in (1) but entering `0:20:00` works, `ModelState.IsValid == true` and the SlotDuration bound value is correct.
3. If I remove the regex attribute, the validation and binding works correctly for `0:20:00`; using `20:00` results in a 20 hour timespan.
4. The following code outputs
   `20:00 --> 00:20:00` `match`

   ```
   string value = null;
   TimeSpan interval;
   var rg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"((0?0:)?([0-3]?[0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?)");
   value = "10:25";
   if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, @"mm\:ss", null, out interval))
       Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", value, interval.ToString("c"));
   else
       Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'", value);
   if (rg.IsMatch(value))
       Console.WriteLine("match");
   else
       Console.WriteLine("no match");
   ```

Questions:

- Why does the validation fail even though the regex does match and the string can be parsed as TimeSpan, even though not in the way I want?
- How can I make the ModelBinder use my `DisplayFormat` for converting the entered value to the TimeSpan? Is there another property/attribute/... which achieves this?